# SQL não tem nenhum resultado após usar bind

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Fiz este código para criar *databases*:

```
public function addDatabase($name, $collation) {   
        try {
            $sql = "CREATE DATABASE `:name` COLLATE `:collation`;";

            // Prepare the query to execute
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            $parameters = array(':name' => $name, ':collation' => $collation);

            // Execute the query
            $query->execute($parameters);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Ele não estava exibindo nenhum erro e nenhum resultado... Refiz o código sem *bind*

```
public function addDatabase($name, $collation) {   
    try {
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE `$name` COLLATE `$collation`;";

        // Prepare the query to execute
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        // Execute the query
        $query->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

E sem *bind* funcionou. Porém não posso deixar sem *bind* para evitar *SQL injection*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto não vai funcionar mesmo. O *binding* funciona para substituição de dados que devem ser usados na consulta. Ele não funciona para substituir qualquer parte do texto da consulta. Ele não é um substituto de *strings* que magicamente resolvem problemas de injeção de código. Ele consegue fazer isto justamente porque sua função é limitada, ele sabe como lidar com os dados que virão de fontes não confiáveis para colocar em locais bem específicos da *query* que são justamente onde deveria ter **dados**.

Então não tem muita solução a não ser ir pelo segundo caminho. Se o que vem de `$name` e `$collation` não são confiáveis o seu código terá que dar tratamento adequado para que uma injeção não ocorra neste caso. Esta verificação terá que ser feita manualmente. É um bom exercício. E estamos aqui para ir ajudando com dúvidas específicas que você tenha no meio do processo.

Teria que verificar o conteúdo individualmente dentro do que é esperado. Tem que ver, por exemplo, se tem só uma palavra em `$name` ou o mesmo em `$collation`, mas neste caso seria bom verificar também se está dentro de uma lista de palavras aceitáveis. Ou seja, tem que limpar possíveis "sujeiras" que possam vir ou recusar o que vem se há presença de "sujeira".

A biblioteca que não usa PDO possui a função [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) que ajuda nisto - mas não resolve o problema por si só. O PDO não tem uma e não sei se pode ser usado a do `mysqli`. Existe a  [`PDO::quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) mas não sei se ela é equivalente.

Eu sou crítico ao uso do PDO, eu acho que ele traz mais problemas que soluções na maioria dos casos. E nos casos que traz uma solução razoável que é abstrair vários bancos de dados - o que raramente é necessário e usado de fato - ainda assim continua tendo problemas. Infelizmente seu uso é disseminado como se fosse solução mágica e perfeita para todos os problemas. E normalmente quem não entende todas as implicações do seu uso acaba comprando gato por lebre.

Um [ponto de partida para estudar mais sobre o assunto de injeção de SQL](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). [Documentação específica do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: De fato o PDO::quote é similar ao mysqli_real_escape_string. Por curiosidade, quais os problemas que o PDO traz?

Comment: Um dos maiores problema é que deixa mais lento, o que pode ser contra argumentado que PHP já é lento mesmo então não importa. Não tem tudo que a API nativa, nem perto. Cria a ilusão de que pode facilmente trocar de banco de dados, o que eu acho ruim porque a pessoa faz tudo pensando nessa falácia. A API me parece menos intuitiva talvez por tentar generalizar demais. Na época tinha mais desvantagens que hoje, ele até arrumou alguma coisa. não sei dizer quanto então posso falar de algo que resolveu, mas era menos seguro, não era tão flexível, coisas resolvíveis, por isso não quero afirmar

Comment: e deve ter algo mais que não me lembro agora, até pq faz mais de 10 anos que não mexo com isso.

Comment: @gmsantos O primeiro e mais gritante problema - que agora foi "mais ou menos" sanado é o fato do PDO simular prepared statements por padrão - parece que mais recentemente mudaram isso um pouco, mas ficou com esse problema sério muito tempo. Fora isso é uma camada a mais entre o DB e a linguagem, o que por si só torna tudo mais complexo e aumenta a superfície de bugs (ou seja, vai ter todos que o driver nativo tiver, e mais os do PDO, que só acrescenta camadas). E cria a ilusão de que pode trocar de DB, mas na prática sempre tem que reescrever. Quase sempre traz mais problema que benefício.